# Knex resolving empty set after insert

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to setup a basic database connection in Node using Postgresql and [Knex](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex), but I'm having trouble getting what seems like a simple insert to work. I'm basing most of this code on the example code in the Knex github repo.

The issue seems to be that my first insert (where I add the admin user) is resolving an empty set of rows (not really sure since the documentation doesn't contain any info on rows or row sets as far as I can find).

Here is my code:

```
const knex = require("knex")({
  client: "postgres",
  connection: {
    host     : "127.0.0.1",
    user     : "postgres",
    password : "my password goes here",
    database : "issue-tracker",
    charset  : "utf8"
  }
});

knex.schema
  .dropTableIfExists("tickets")
  .dropTableIfExists("users")
  .createTable("users", createUserTable)
  .createTable("tickets", createTicketTable)
  .then(() => addTestData())
  .then(() => console.log("Done"))
  .catch((e) => console.log(e));

function createUserTable(table) {
  table.increments("id");
  table.string("username").index().unique();
  table.string("password");
  table.timestamps();
}

function createTicketTable(table) {
  table.increments("id");
  table.timestamps();
  table.integer("creator_id").unsigned().references("users.id");
  table.string("text");
}

function addTestData() {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() =>
      knex.insert({username: "admin", password: "password"})
      .into("users")
    )
    .then((rows) =>
      // rows is empty?
      knex.insert({creator_id: rows[0], text: "this is a test"})
      .into("tickets")
    )
    .then(() =>
      knex("users").join("tickets", "users.id", "tickets.creator_id")
      .select("users.id as creator_id", "users.username as creator_name", "tickets.text as text")
    )
    .then(console.log.bind(console));
}
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Promise handlers must return something. It works like an assembly line - each station must put the results of its work back onto the line.

- Insert operations in knex do not return rows unless you explicitly tell them to. Knex has `.returning()` for that ([docs](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-returning)).
- Your last handler in the chain (`console.log.bind(console)`) returns nothing, hence the final result of the chain is undefined.
- You do not need to start the promise chain with `Promise.resolve()`. You can start it with any promise-returning function - using `knex()` directly is sensible here.

So, slightly re-arranged, we end up with this:

```
function addTestData() {
    return knex("users")
        .returning("user_id")
        .insert({username: "admin", password: "password"})
        .then((rows) => {
            return knex("tickets")
                .returning("ticket_id")
                .insert({creator_id: rows[0], text: "this is a test"});
        })
        .then((rows) => {
            return knex("users")
                .join("tickets", "users.id", "tickets.creator_id")
                .select("users.id as creator_id", "users.username as creator_name", "tickets.text as text");
        })
        .then((rows) => {
            console.log.bind(console);
            return rows;
        });
}
```

this is equivalent to this, where the `return` is implied and therefore less obvious:

```
function addTestData() {
    return knex("users")
        .returning("user_id")
        .insert({username: "admin", password: "password"})
        .then((rows) => knex("tickets")
            .returning("ticket_id")
            .insert({creator_id: rows[0], text: "this is a test"});
        })
        .then((rows) => knex("users")
            .join("tickets", "users.id", "tickets.creator_id")
            .select("users.id as creator_id", "users.username as creator_name", "tickets.text as text");
        })
        .then((rows) => {
            console.log.bind(console);
            return rows;
        });
}
```

Comment: This isn't the problem. I'm not trying to resolve any value. I'm just trying to insert a user, resolve its id, and insert a ticket (with its creator_id set to the inserted user's id). `addTestData` can resolve nothing for all I care. The problem is that `rows` is empty after the first insert.

Comment: Ah. Insert statements typically return no rows. See https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/732 for a way to get the inserted value.

Comment: Thank you! The issue was I wasn't using the `returning` method. Its working now. If you want to edit your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I'll edit it as soon as I'm home. I am not prepared for the pain of doing it on my mobile. :)